# TWS SAP Task String: What does the -c parameter define?

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

Tivoli Workload Scheduler 8.6.0.2

I have reviewed all of the documentation I can find, official and non-official. When defining an SAP R/3 process chain task string, what does the -c flag do?

For example, I have a task string that calls an APO process chain that looks like:

```
                               vvvv
-- / -job ChainName -i pchain_ -c C -flag DISABLE_PCHAINLOG
                               ^^^^
```

TIA,

Mike

Comment: The [TWS 8.6 User Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTG2Y_8.6.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_8.6.0.1/awsaubiwiptaskstr.htm) is helpful, but does not seem to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I believe it is the Class setting. The default class is "C", which is why all of our existing PC's have -c C in the task string. I presume I can configure -c A for Class "A", and -c B for Class "B".

EDIT: Confirmed:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTG2Y_8.6.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_8.6.0.1/awsaur3task.htm